# Gradient decent using Taylor Series

Tags: taylor-expansion, first-order-logic, descent

I'm reading a book about Gradient methods right now, where
the author is using a [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) to explain/derive
an equation.

$$ \mathbf x_a = \mathbf x - \alpha \mathbf{ \nabla f } (\mathbf x ) $$

Now he says the first order expansion of the [Taylor series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) around x would look
like this:

$$ \mathbf{ f } (\mathbf x_a ) = \mathbf{ f } (\mathbf x ) + \mathbf{ \nabla f } (\mathbf x )'( \mathbf x_a - \mathbf x ) + \mathbf o ( || \mathbf x_a - \mathbf x || )$$

and the simplifies it to:

$$ \mathbf{ f } (\mathbf x_a ) = \mathbf{ f } (\mathbf x ) + \alpha || \mathbf{ \nabla f } (\mathbf x )||^2 + \mathbf o (\alpha)$$

Now I don't get this part $ \mathbf o ( || \mathbf x_a - \mathbf x || ) $. As far as I know
it's not part of the Taylor Series. Furthermore since I don't know what $ \mathbf o () $ is I can't understand how he can simplify it to $ \mathbf o ( \alpha ) $.

Comment: can you put a link to the article where you found the proof?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I can not provide the original source. It's been too long and I found better literature for my purposes.

Comment: How is this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$o()$ refers to the [Landau notation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

$$ f ( x_\alpha ) = f ( x ) + { \nabla f } ( x )'(  x_a -  x ) +  o ( ||  x_a -  x || )$$

Plugin the definition  of $x_a$

$$= f ( x ) +  \nabla f ( x )'(  x - \alpha  \nabla f ( x ) -  x ) +  o ( ||  x - \alpha { \nabla f } ( x ) -  x || )  $$

$$ = f ( x ) +  \nabla f ( x )'(  - \alpha  \nabla f  ( x ) ) +  o ( ||- \alpha { \nabla f } ( x ) || ) \qquad \qquad \quad$$

And by definition of $o$ and $||\cdot||$

$$ = f ( x ) -\alpha \underbrace{  \nabla f  ( x )' \nabla f  ( x )}_{||\nabla f(x)||^2}  +  \underbrace{o ( \alpha ||  { \nabla f } ( x ) || )}_{o(\alpha)} \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad \: \: \:$$

Comment: Why is the part with the Landau Notation included to the Taylor Series?

Comment: $o(g)$ means (roughly) that there are more therms which converge to zero faster than $g$. So here we just consider the first few terms of the taylor series.

Comment: @Nimi Note that the Taylor expansion has an *infinite* number of terms. Also, as a side note: some methods in fact use more than just the first two terms (e.g. BFGS constructs the local Hessian).

Comment: Could you pls explains why it is allowed to ignore $ || \nabla f(x) || $ in o()?

Comment: Because constants do change the behaivour of growth, you can look up the definition of $o()$ here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation and there is a nice comparitions of the different 'o's in the table right below there. Further down you find a lot more examples. You have to understand $o(g)$ represents a whole class of functions.

Answer (score 1):

The equation 
\begin{equation*}
f(x_a) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T (x_a - x) + o(\|x_a - x \|)
\end{equation*}
is a short way of saying that if $r(x_a)$ is defined by the equation
\begin{equation*}
f(x_a) = f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T (x_a - x) + r(x_a),
\end{equation*}
then $r(x_a)$ is small even when compared with $\| x_a - x\|$.

More precisely, 
\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x_a \to x} \frac{|r(x_a)|}{\|x_a - x\|} = 0.
\end{equation*}